# Add database model (for listing records) to a View associated already with a model (for textboxes)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm quite new to MVC and still making myself familiar to how MVC works. So basically, I have a **User** `model` that has a **Create** `view`. I'm using `Razor` syntax to get the variables from **User** `model`:

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model CDS.Models.UserModels
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create User";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.firstname)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstname)
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

**UserModels.cs**

```
namespace CDS.Models
{
    public class UserModels
    {
        public string userid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string firstname{ get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> filteroptions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried auto-generating an **Index** `view` from the controller's `Index` method to list the database records, but found out that the generated **Index** `view` is using the `Database` `model` (first line of code). I just want to move the code from the Index.cshtml to my Create.cshtml to have the latter `View` also display the database records. So how will I do that? I've heard that I need to use Javascript for that?

**UserController.cs**

```
namespace CDS.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        CDSEntities _odb = new CDSEntities(); //My Database

        // GET: User
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_odb.USR_MSTR.ToList());
        }

        // GET: User/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var filters = GetAllFilters();
            var model = new UserModels();
            model.filteroptions = GetSelectListItems(filters);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<CDS.USR_MSTR>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FIRST_NM)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LAST_NM)</th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FIRST_NM)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LAST_NM)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Please note that I removed the codes that I think unnecessary to post here. These are all just summaries of my classes and HTMLs

Comment: because you are returning a list of `USR_GRP_MSTR` to view, the `Index.cshtml` is created using this model. You need to return a list of `UserModels`.

Comment: But if I return `UserModels`, it will only let me use the variables declared in the `UserModels` class. Not the actual database table. By the way, it's not `USR_GRP_MSTR`, I changed it to `USR_MSTR`. And I added my current `Create` method in my sample, that returns a list for my filter dropdownbox

Comment: In your `Index.cshtml` view, add `@Html.Action("Create")` to load the form into your view (and change the `Create()` method to `return PartialView();`) Alternatively create a view model to represent what you ant to display/edit in the view.